# How to implement a notification queue for push notificatoins in backend?

Tags: django, notifications, scheduled-tasks

Let's say I have users who create events of different time periods(max: 7days), and I have to send notifications to users when their event has ended. In between the time of each event, a user can cancel that event.

To accomplish this I had the following implementation in mind:

- Mimic a priority queue using a database:
  Put the events in a database indexed and sorted by end time of events and erase events on deletion by the user or when it becomes the topmost event and current time is greater than its end time.

This would mean I would have to poll the database every time to check for completed events. Considering that, I am not sure whether this is the right way to do this.

So my question is are there any better methods or better, existing technologies that help to accomplish this sort of behavior?

PS: Currently my backend is in django, so technologies easily integratable with django would be preferred.

Comment: You could create a `Notification` `model` with 2 relationships to `User` and an `Event`  and a function that creates a notification for a requested `user` about a given `event` being over when such thing happens and call it in 2 separate places in your code: When time expires and when user manually cancells it.